# Open graph approval time

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Can anyone tell me the time it takes for a request for approval of actions in the open graph system is answered. I have been waiting for a week now. Maybe my request doesn't meet the requirments, but I believe it does. Can I contact anyone at FB?

Comment: Please do contact someone at Facebook - this isn't Facebook support. It's like me asking how long Microsoft will take to send a copy of Windows 8 through the mail.

Answer (score 1):

It only took me 2 days but it varies.